# Can I add a link inside an object value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink

I have an object that I am using to store data I want available on my site, and I would like to add a link inside the value. Example -

```
  s3: {
    title: "Title",
    description: "I want to describe a website and provide a link in here",
  },
```

I want the "here" to be a link.

I've tried with the link() method -

```
const linkName = "Here"
const link = linkName.link("http://www.google.com")

  description: "I want to describe a website and provide a" + link + "in here",
```

but that just shows the literal HTML after I loop through the object and display it, not an actual link.

*Edit - I am using React to display the data. Example -

```
  Object.keys(object).map(function (key) {
    return <Card
      title={object[key].title}
      description={object[key].description}
    />;
  });
```

Comment: *How* are you generating the HTML from this object?

Comment: How are you trying to display the link?

Comment: And how are you inserting the description in page? Can certainly use html in strings so long as you insert them as html and not text

Comment: I am using React, I'll edit my post with the code since it's long

Comment: Does the <Card> description accept html? `'My link is: <a href="http://...">Click me</a>'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing fancy about that at all...

```
 s3: {
    title: "Title",
    description: "I want to describe a website and provide a link in here",
  }
//any "link" is just a string that represents a url... thus just store it as a property=>String like so.

s3.link = "putYourUrlHere";


//or another way is in the declartion of the object literal.

 s3: {
    title: "Title",
    description: "I want to describe a website and provide a link in here",
    link: "putYourUrlHere";
  }



//but then you have to generate html from an object.
//so maybe something like this?


 s3: {
    title: "Title",
    descript1: "I want to describe a website and provide ",
    descript2: " in here",
    link: "putYourUrlHere";
  }




const div = document.createElement('div');
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('src', s3.link);
const p1 = document.createElement('p');
const p2 = document.createElement('p');
p1.innerHTML = s3.descript1;
p2.innerHTML = s3.descript2;
div.appendChild(p1);
div.appendChild(a);
div.appendChild(p2);


//that's if you want it in the middle, or a specific part of the description.
```

edit: fixed concatenation error

Comment: You can't concatenate a string and an element.

Comment: fixed. small derp on my part. basic idea is still the same.